# ViewModel with IDataErrorInfo always calls getter after setting property?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I want to give this question as much context as possible, but, in summary, I'm basically asking two questions:

- Does WPF always call the getter after setting a bound property when the setter doesn't throw an exception?
- Is it possible to prevent the getter of a bound property from being called after an error has occurred in the setter when the ViewModel implements `IDataErrorInfo`?

I currently have a Model class that implements validation by throwing an exception from the property setter.  Additionally, many of the properties are coupled, so modifying the value of one of them may cause several others to be recalculated.  It implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` to alert outside listeners whenever a recalculation has occurred.  It looks something like this:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double property1;
    public double Property1
    {
        get { return property1; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0.0)
                throw new Exception("Property1 cannot be less than 0.0.");

            property1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Property1"));
        }
    }

    // ...Everything needed to support INotifyPropertyChanged...
}
```

Initially, I implemented the ViewModel for this class to act as a thin wrapper around the model properties, providing additional view-specific behaviors whenever an error occurs (flagging invalid data, disabling buttons, etc.):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Model model;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        model = new Model();
        model.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged(args);
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return model.Property1.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                model.Property1 = Double.Parse(value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Perform any view-specific actions
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...Everything needed to support INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Notably, the ViewModel doesn't have any additional backing fields; all of its properties are directly linked to the corresponding properties in the Model, and any `PropertyChanged` notifications from the Model are passed along by the ViewModel.

But, I've frequently heard that using exceptions for validation can be limiting, and I'm starting to realize the same, specifically as the need for cross-coupled validation rules has increased in this application.

I didn't want to change behaviors of the Model, since it is already being used in several other places, but I went about changing the ViewModel to implement `IDataErrorInfo`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Model model;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        model = new Model();
        model.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => 
        {
            errorList.Remove(args.PropertyName);
            OnPropertyChanged(args);
        };
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return model.Property1.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                model.Property1 = Double.Parse(value);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Perform any view-specific actions                    
                errorList["Property1"] = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> errorList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string errorMessage;
            if (errorList.TryGetValue(propertyName, out errorMessage))
                return errorMessage;
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Error { get { return String.Empty; } }

    // ...Everything needed to support INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

However, this caused a drastic unwanted change in behavior.  When using exceptions, after the user entered an invalid value, the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` for the control is displayed and the invalid value remains in the control, thus giving the user the opportunity to correct their mistake.  When using `IDataErrorInfo`, WPF seems to call the property getter after the setter has completed.  Since the Model hasn't changed whenever an error occurs, the invalid value is replaced by the previous value.  So now I have a control displaying the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` but with a VALID being value displayed!

It seems crazy to me that WPF would automatically call a property getter without receiving a `PropertyChanged` notification (after the window has been initialized).  And it doesn't attempt to call the getter after an exception is thrown, so why would it do it when `IDataErrorInfo` is used?

Am I doing something wrong that's causing this behavior?  Is there a way to prevent WPF from calling the property getter in the ViewModel after an error has occurred in the setter when the ViewModel implements `IDataErrorInfo`?

I've tried adding backing fields to the ViewModel to store the invalid value, but due to the fact Model properties can be modified outside of the ViewModel (that's the reason it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the first place), the solution ends up being quite complex and basically unsustainable in an environment with programmers of varying skill levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't answer the questions I asked, my coworker suggested that the desired behavior could be achieved by adding the invalid value to the `errorList` and modifying the getter in the ViewModel to return the invalid value whenever there is an error.

So the properties in the ViewModel look like this:

```
public string Property1
{
    get
    {
        ErrorInfo error;
        if (errorList.TryGetValue("Property1", out error))
            return error.Value;

        return model.Property1.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            model.Property1 = Double.Parse(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Perform any view-specific actions
            errorList["Property1"] = new ErrorInfo(value, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

With the following updates to the `IDataErrorInfo` methods:

```
private struct ErrorInfo
{
    public readonly string Value;
    public readonly string Message;

    public ErrorInfo(string value, string message)
    {
        Value = value;
        Message = message;
    }
}

private readonly Dictionary<string, ErrorInfo> errorList = new Dictionary<string, ErrorInfo>();

public string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        ErrorInfo error;
        if (errorList.TryGetValue(propertyName, out error))
            return error.Message;
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

public string Error { get { return String.Empty; } }
```

This allows the `PropertyChanged` event handler to stay the same, and only requires small changes to the property getters and setters.

Comment: While neither answer attempts to address the questions I asked, this one more closely matches my original design intent, without requiring me to change the Model to better fit the requirements of the View. I still have a hard time accepting that using MVVM requires me to design my business objects in a certain way. That really seems like it violates the entire point of using separate application layers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach you want to have for [form validation in MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM)

Your model

```
public class Product:IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string ProductName {get;set;}

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
       get 
       {
           string validationResult = null;
           switch (propertyName)
           {
               case "ProductName":
               validationResult = ValidateName();
           }
       }
     }
}
```

Then in your ViewModel

```
public string ProductName
{
  get { return currentProduct.ProductName; }
  set 
  {
    if (currentProduct.ProductName != value)
    {
      currentProduct.ProductName = value;
      base.OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
    }
  }  
}
```

As another consideration, when I want to validate numbers (such as your double validation), keep the model as having a double instead of a string

```
public double? Property1 {get;set;}
```

then you can do this

```
<Textbox Name="myDoubleTextbox" >
    <Binding ValidatesOnDataErrors="true" Path="Property1" TargetValueNull="" />
/>
```

so when they type something incorrect into the double box, it sends null to your model and you can check against that.

Comment: Good suggestions, especially about using `double?` in the Model and `TargetValueNull` in the XAML.  Although I still have a hard time with the idea that the Model should be changed to fit the behavior of the View.  I had thought that the Model is supposed to capture the business logic in whatever way is most intuitive for itself, the View is supposed to capture the presentation in whatever way is most intuitive for itself, and then the ViewModel handles the interaction between them.  Do I just need to accept that everything is easier when the design the Model is based on the needs of the View?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when you say "design the model based on the needs of the view". Say you have some money. It would be best represented by using some number type, not a string type. If we constructed a view of the money, what we would see would look like a string. We could easily build a model and bind all our data to strings, but that would be a representation of the view, not a representation of what we are modeling.

Comment: Ah, ok; I meant it with respect to the validation and `IDataErrorInfo`.  In this particular situation, it's better for the Model to never contain invalid data.  The validation should occur immediately within the setter and reject all bad data (just like throwing an `ArgumentNullException`).  That's what makes the most sense based on the business requirements.  Why then should the Model be changed to accept all possible numbers, strings, etc. and require a separate call to a validation method (which could be forgotten)?  Isn't that a UI requirement creeping into the Model specification?

Comment: (And I'm legitimately interested in an answer.  I promise I'm not just trying to be argumentative.)

Comment: You can code your model to use all string types instead of ints and doubles ect... But think about how you would use that model across your application. Likely if you're using number types you want to perform calculations with them. Now you're forced to convert your strings to doubles, strings to ints all over the place. It's as much of philosophy as it's for keeping your code much cleaner.

Comment: Sure, I get that.  But I'm concerned about more complex validation logic than just type conversion.  What if I need to enforce that a value is always between 0 and 90?  Perhaps it represents a tool angle on a manufacturing machine that will break and cause injury if the angle is outside that range.  The Model property can be a double, but it still must reject values outside this range, and it seems like the logical place to do that is in the setter with an exception.  Is there a compelling reason besides UI to change the Model property to accept all doubles and have an extra validation method?